# pageup and pagedown does not work in vim using konsole

Tags: linux, dictionary, vim, sles, konsole

I have just recently moved to SLES12 from SLES11

Using vim in SLES11 pageup and page down worked perfectly while SLES12 it is not. (in gvim - it does work)

I am trying several solutions written in others threads like without success :(

```
map <CTRL-V><CTRL-PAGEUP> :tabp<CR>

map <C-PageUp> :echo "hello"<CR>

map ^[[5^ :echo "hello"<CR>
```

I think it might related to the fact of the bindkeys of the terminals as one of the threads mention- but I do not find which one is related to pageup/down.

any clue?

Comment: Are you trying to map `<CTRL-PAGEUP>` or `<PAGEUP>` ? What do you see if you type `:<CTRL-V><PAGEUP>` ?

Comment: I am trying to make PAGEUP and PAGEDOWN to work in vim. so I am not sure what I need to map to it. 
other threads suggested it-

Comment: Can you answer my second question ? Do you see `^[[5^` or `^[[5~` ?

Comment: you mean in vim itself right?
CTRL-V - makes it visual block. 
if I am in in insert mode, then CTRL-V , inserts ^
and PAGEUP inserts P
and if in the command line - I get Trainling Char

Comment: yes, in vim itself. Also, have you tried `map <PageUp> :echo "hello"<CR>` ?

Comment: tried it now and it did not work :(

Comment: When I type `:` then `Ctrl-V` then `PageUp`, I see `^[[5~`. What did you see ?

Comment: I am getting only this ^

Comment: That means your terminal is not setup properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226324/discussion-between-user8253554-and-philippe).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the way your terminal is set up.
As you have stated you are using Konsole, you can check the settings by right clicking on an open terminal window and selecting `Edit Current Profile`:

[image]

That should open up another window like:

[image]

On this screen select the keyboard option on the left and check your keyboards. For a quick win you can try changing the keybinding or reset to default. If that isn't enough you will need to go into the keybinding and ensure the `PgUp` is producing the expected code: `^[[5~`. Doing so *should* be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer . When I am using edit and pressing `PgUp` - nothing happens. other buttons like `Home` and `End` do returns codes

Comment: Oh interesting, it must be a deeper problem then. I'm assuming that `PgUp` works in other applications?

Comment: define other applications :) - in other terminals like gnome-terminal it does. in less in konsole it does not